# Maatwebsite excel library v2.1 how to remove an extra colum generated by the library that i don't need

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

i write this code.

```
       Excel::create("actes".Carbon::now(), function($excel) {
       $excel->sheet("TARIF PARTICULIER", function($sheet) {
        $categs=$_REQUEST['categs'];
        $actes=Acte::join("categorie_acte","acte.categorie_id","categorie_acte.id")
            ->join("tarif_acte","tarif_acte.id_acte","acte.id")
            ->join("tarif","tarif_acte.id_tarif","tarif.id")
            ->whereIn('categorie_acte.id',$categs)
            ->where('deleted',Product::PRODUCT_UP)
            ->where(['acte.centre_id'=>session("currentcentre"),
            'tarif.centre_id'=>session("currentcentre")])
            ->whereIn("tarif.libelle",["TARIF PARTICULIER","Tarif 
            particulier",'Particuliers'])
            ->orderBy("acte.libelle")
            ->select("acte.libelle as Nom","tarif_acte.prix as Prix", 
            "categorie_acte.libelle as Categorie")
            ->get();
          if($actes&&!empty($actes))
           $sheet->fromArray($actes->toArray(), null, 'A1', true);
       });
      })->export('xls');
```

i expect this response

[image: expected result]

but what i get is this:

[image]

there is an extra column (the last one name categrie) witch i never mentioned in my request. I want your help to know how it appear and how to avoid it. thank you.

Comment: did you try dumping the value of `$actes`?

Comment: yes @CésarEscudero but there no 'categorie' column, i don't know how it come in excel file